# Ajax success function returns empty data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to navigate my request through ajax.

When a user is authenticated it goes to another url on ajax success function -

```
success:function(data,result)
{
window.location.url='@Url.Action("Home","Index");
}
```

And my **controller** is-

```
 public void _LoginPartial(LoginModel login) {
            try {

                var system = (from u in db.RegisterLedgers
                              where u.EmailID == login.EmailID && u.RegisteredPassword == login.PaSsWoRd
                              select u).FirstOrDefault();
                if (system != null) {

                    Session["LoggedInUser"] = system;
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(system.RegisteredName, false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);
            }
        }
```

Ajax query is-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Login-button').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/loginledger/_loginpartial/',
                data: $('#form-loginpartial').serialize(),
                type: 'post',
                success: function (data, result) {
                    alert(result);
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Form couldn't be submitted");
                }

            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

It shows that ajax query is successful but the data comes empty. I checked this request on server side and it fetches out record from database.

Why I am getting empty result in ajax success function? What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What did I do wrong here?

Your controller action doesn't seem to return anything. It's just a `void`. In ASP.NET MVC Controller actions must return ActionResults.

For example you could a JsonResult

```
public ActionResult _LoginPartial(LoginModel login) 
{
    try 
    {
        var system = 
            (from u in db.RegisterLedgers
            where u.EmailID == login.EmailID && u.RegisteredPassword == login.PaSsWoRd
            select u).FirstOrDefault();

        if (system != null) 
        {
            Session["LoggedInUser"] = system;
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(system.RegisteredName, false);
            return Json(new { success = true; });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);
    }

    return Json(new { success = false; });
}
```

which you could check in your AJAX success callback:

```
success: function (data) {
    alert(data.success);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `_LoginPartial` action has no return type (`void`). You have to set a return type for the `_LoginPartial` action, then return something. e.g. `return View()` or `return Json()`.

Revised signature:

```
public ActionResult _LoginPartial(LoginModel login)
{
    // also a good idea to check `ModelState.IsValid`
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Go ahead and log them in if everything checks out, then return
        // your successful response
        return Json(new { status = 200, msg = "OK" });
    }
    // Erroneous response
    return Json(new { status = 401, msg = "Unauthorized" });
}
```

Just examples given; Obviously implement it as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Your action should return something (recommended JsonResult). To do this please replace return type (void) with ActionResult or JsonResult and in the end of function return Json() something like that:

```
public ActionResult_LoginPartial(LoginModel login) {
        try {

            var system = (from u in db.RegisterLedgers
                          where u.EmailID == login.EmailID && u.RegisteredPassword == login.PaSsWoRd
                          select u).FirstOrDefault();
            if (system != null) {

                Session["LoggedInUser"] = system;
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(system.RegisteredName, false);

             return Json(data = result, message = "suceed" JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

          return Json(data=null, message = "system is null" JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);
            return Json(data=null, message = "exception" JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```